# recording my screen view app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am building an application that records everything going on on my screen, i have many views and a camera view opening, i have tried:

```
ASScreenRecorder *recorder = [ASScreenRecorder sharedInstance];

if (recorder.isRecording) {
    [recorder stopRecordingWithCompletion:^{
        NSLog(@"Finished recording");
    }];
} else {
    [recorder startRecording];
    NSLog(@"Start recording");
}
```

from ASScreenRecorder, and also Glimpse library, but every time it seems to record everything but the camera view, it shows as blank, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the iOS framework ReplayKit?

Comment: using ReplayKit freezes the camera view, i am using AVCapture,

Comment: actually this might work, but is there a way to crop the recording view of ReplayKit?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to take a screenshot of AVPlayer. You can use `AVAssetImageGenerator` to get the required image from `AVAsset` and then Merge/Blend it with the screenshot you are getting from `ASScreenRecorder`.

Getting image from AVAsset (Sample code):

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:sourceURL];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```